# How do I remap result navigation buttons after a search?

Tags: key-bindings, search

I search with `/`, press enter, and go a few results down using `n`.
I realize that I have gone a few more results down than I meant to and want to go back a few.
I press `m` because that is next to `n` just like `k` is next to `j`. Nothing happens because `m` is not `N`.

How can I remap `N` to `m` in the context of navigating search results?

Edit: I am using neovim in case that makes a difference ;)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Interesting question. Do you want to remap N to m only when searching or all the time?

Comment: Ideally only when searching. I was not aware that it had a function outside the search context (I only started using vim regularly last week). Does it? `:help n` goes to the search help.

Comment: Ok. It marks, actually, which is a nice feature. I’m not sure vim can tell when it’s searching explicitly (bc you can search, navigate, edit, save the file, whatever, and whenever you hit `n` again it picks up the search), so ultimately answers will probably be « You can do it permanently, but this overrides the mark feature which is useful ». I’ll try to write one at some point

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the clarification @D.BenKnoble

Comment: Agreeing with @Ben here: You should get used to use `N` and not try to remap it to `m` for several reasons: If you remap it permanently you loose the mark feature, if you remap it "only when searching" it will be hacky (probably buggy), non trivial to implement and with very few (or none) added value. A good rule of thumb when starting to use Vim is: Don't remap an existing feature (e.g searching backward) only remap something which can't be done out of the box (e.g. center the next search result in the middle of the screen). That allows you to get used to vanilla vim which is good.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the approach (although I agree that it is hacky in this case and probably shouldn't be done). Keeping all the default ones means keeping what bad in the default vim, instead of trying to improve it.  I personally have remapped `\z` to `m` and remapped `mx` to several things.  It is not that useful so it doesn't deserve a single-key mapping.